# How to create unlimited objects from one submit event in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby, need to create a form for user registration, and user must be able to register limitless number of friends. Want to do it like so: begin with single form and `add` button. If user clicks on `add` button the first form is copied and so on. In the end there is only one submit button which submits all forms. Trying to do it, but can't understand how to pass limitless number of objects to the form. Now just passing one object:

`participation_forms_controller.rb`:

```
class ParticipationFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @participation_form = ParticipationForm.new
  end
  ...
```

The problem is I need to create some number of `ParticipationForm` objects but only user determine actual number of that objects. And as I understand , I need to pass the same number of objects from ruby controller to my html. But I don't know how many, so I can't do some sort of loop in controller like that:

```
class ParticipationFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @participation_forms = []
    <dont_know_how_many>.times do
    @participation_forms << ParticipationForm.new
    end
  end
```

I've thought about some sort of dirty hack: copy all data from other forms  to the first and then submit only the first. But want to do it in good fashion way as normal coders do. What I can do if I used `python`: just make one form with fieldnames like `username_1`, `userdata_1`, `username_2`, `userdata_2` and so on, then just parse them on backend. But ruby is somewhat strict about what parameters i can pass to the controller, i must predefine them, so can't do that trick? What is my `create` controller:

```
  def create
    @participation_form = ParticipationForm.new(article_params)

    @participation_form.save
    render 'new'
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:participation_form).permit(
        :name, :telephone, :email, :post, :image)
    end
```

So how can I pass there something like `name_999`? No way, ruby is rigorous.
It will be awesome if in ruby I can use regexp to allow set of fields, just my fantasy-code:

```
def article_params

  params.require(:participation_form).permit(
    :re.match('^name_\d*$'))
  end
```

If it will be real then I can use one form for this task.

**frontend code snippet of-what-i-want**

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var addFriendForm = function() {
    $('.button-group__add-friend-btn').click(function() {
      forms = $(".form-signin");
      var first = forms.first();
      var first_clone = first.clone();
      first_clone_children = first_clone.children();
      $(first_clone_children).each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('form-signin__file-upload')) {
          file_upload_children = $(this).children();
          file_upload_children.each(function() {
            this.value = '';
          });
        }
        else {
          this.value = '';
        }
      });
      var last = forms.last();
      first_clone.insertAfter(last);
      $('<hr class="container__hr">').insertAfter(last);
      changeRegBtnText();
      addDelBtn();
    });
  };
  
  var changeRegBtnText = function(back_to_one=false) {
    var one = 'register'
    var plural = 'register with friends';
    var btn = $('.button-group__add-reg-btn');
    if (btn.text() == one) {
      btn.html(plural);
    }
    else if (back_to_one) {
      btn.html(one);
    }
  };
  
  var addDelBtn = function() {
    var del_btn = $("#friend_del_btn");
    if (del_btn.hasClass("button-group__del-friend-btn_disabled")) {
      del_btn.removeClass("button-group__del-friend-btn_disabled");
      del_btn.addClass("button-group__del-friend-btn_active");
    }
  };

  var deleteFriendForm = function() {
    $('#friend_del_btn').click(function() {
      forms = $(".form-signin");
      hrs = $('.container__hr');
      var last_fieldset = forms.last();
      last_fieldset.remove();
      var last_hr = hrs.last();
      last_hr.remove();
      if ($(".form-signin").length == 1) {
        changeRegBtnText(back_to_one=true);
        $("#friend_del_btn").addClass("button-group__del-friend-btn_disabled");
      }
    });
  };

  var submitForms = function() {
    $(".button-group__add-reg-btn").on("click", function(e) {
      $(".form-signin").each(function(){
        $(this).trigger("submit");
        console.log('submit');
      });
    });
  }

  addFriendForm();
  deleteFriendForm();
  submitForms();

});
```

```css
.form-control {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container__hr {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  height: 1px;
  width: 300px;
}

.form-signin__file-upload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-signin__file-upload-filename {
  float: left;
  color: #222;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.form-signin__file-upload-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.form-signin__file-upload-span {
  line-height: 1.42;
  color: black;
}

.button-group {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.button-group__add-friend-btn,
.button-group__add-reg-btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-group__del-friend-btn_disabled {
  display: none !important;
}

.button-group__del-friend-btn_active {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="text-center">Register to conference</h3>
  <form class="form-signin">
    <input type="text" name="[participation_form]name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" required autofocus>
    <input type="tel" name="[participation_form]telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон" required>
    <input type="email" name="[participation_form]email" class="form-control" placeholder="Електропочта" required>
    <input type="text" name="[participation_form]post" class="form-control" placeholder="Должность" required>
    <div class="form-signin__file-upload btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">
      <input class="form-signin__file-upload-filename">
      <input type="file" name="[participation_form]image" class="form-control form-signin__file-upload-input" required>
      <span class="form-signin__file-upload-span">аватар</span>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="text-center button-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-group__add-friend-btn">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> add friend
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="friend_del_btn" class="btn btn-default button-group__del-friend-btn_disabled">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> del friend
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block button-group__add-reg-btn" type="submit">register</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Cool. so... can you please include your code in your question? jsfiddle is awesome, and great that you have provided it, but we also want our Stack Overflow questions to last the test of time, and jsfiddle links go stale pretty quickly. Secondly: what issue/error/problem are you having? ie what are you observing, and what do you expect to observe instead? Why do you think you need to pass unlimited objects to the form? doesn't the form just have fields, and then it passes those fields to your controller that does the actual object-creation?

Comment: basically it's almost all ruby code I have.

Comment: The code that is in your fiddle is also code :) Also - do you have partial templates in `html` or `html.erb`? include those too - ti's part of what we will be deugging to help you out :) Include anything relevant to the question in your `Question` so we can have a look and figure out what needs changing... (we'll also play with the code in the fiddle to figure it out).

Comment: I have one basic `application.html.erb` layout and another html for the form -  you can see it in jsfiddle. The app consists from one page (register form).

Comment: :) please put the form-partial in your question so we can always see it (and the html generated too). Like I said - the jsfiddle will someday go away, and we want our Stack Overflow questions to last forever (in case somebody else has the same problem in the future and finds your question and uses the solutions we come up with). :)

Comment: Ok, I will, copy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is probably not a complete solution, but my first thing to point out is... you should only need a total of one `ParticipationForm` - you don't need to add multiple forms, just multiple sets of user-details fields.

Each set of user-fields will need to be uniquely grouped and identified eg the end-result (after the javascript has added the new fields ech time) would be something like below (note: I've just added a very simple version of the fields, not what you will eventually use with all the details):

```
<form class="form-signin">
  <div class="user-field-set">  
   <input type="text" name="[participation_form][1]name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" required autofocus>
   <input type="tel" name="[participation_form][1]telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон" required>
   <input type="email" name="[participation_form][1]email" class="form-control" placeholder="Електропочта" required>
  </div>
  <div class="user-field-set">  
   <input type="text" name="[participation_form][2]name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" required autofocus>
   <input type="tel" name="[participation_form][2]telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон" required>
   <input type="email" name="[participation_form][2]email" class="form-control" placeholder="Електропочта" required>
  </div>
*** submit button for all sets of user details goes here ***
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, it's one way to do it, appreciate that. But can you please also provide some code in `create` controller for that type of data layout?

Comment: Step 1) update your javascript to insert sets of fields with unique ids like this. Step 2) submit the form and see what params come through to you in your controller then Step 3) we'll see what code we need to parse that set of params :)

Comment: Note that standard Rails practice is to use `form_for` with multiple `fields_for` and then use `accepts_nested_parameters_for :user` (or equivalent model being added here) to accept the multiple user-data in the controller... styart with a fixed number of users (instead of dynamically adding them). Then adapt the html that is generated by `fields_for` to create your javascript dynamic-field-adder... at least that's how I've done it in the past

Comment: Oh, `name="[participation_form][1]name"` this is some kind of array populating-in-html? It's indeed works) Big thanks

Comment: Yeah :) it's something that rails often does with these sets of fields. Then you can just iterate through the array in your controller (though it's often good to see exactly the shape of the params you get before you try to guess how it'll arrive - saves headaches) :)